# How to convert String having contents in XML format into JDom document

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, sax, jdom, jdom-2

How convert String having contents in XML format into JDom document.

i am trying with below code:

```
String docString = txtEditor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(
txtEditor.getEditorInput()).get();

SAXBuilder sb= new SAXBuilder();

doc = sb.build(new StringReader(docString));
```

Can any one help me to resolve above problem.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how you generally parse an xml to Document

```
try {
  SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
  Document anotherDocument = builder.build(new File("/some/directory/sample.xml"));
} catch(JDOMException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is taken from [JDOM IBM Reference](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jdom/)

In case you have string you can convert it to InputStream and then pass it

```
String exampleXML = "<your-xml-string>";
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleXML.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document anotherDocument = builder.build(stream);
```

For the various arguments builder.build() supports you can go through the [api docs](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Code pasted by you works fine to create a new document using the file available at particular path. But in my case, i need to create/convert a string which has content in XML format into Document.

Comment: Yes, code works fine to create a new document from an existing .xml file. But here i don't have any xml file. i getting this string (which has contents in xml format) from some where else.               As you can see it my code:                       String docString = txtEditor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(
txtEditor.getEditorInput()).get();

Comment: sry.. solved the typo issue.. exampleXML is the String in xml format

Comment: Actually, it seems that code pasted by me also working fine. there was problem in somewhere else in my code. But thanks for looking into this. And you provided different way to do the same.Hope this approach will help to any one.

Answer (score 10):

This is a FAQ that shold have an answer more accessible than the actual FAQ: [How do I build a document from a String?](http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0210)

So, I have created [issue #111](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/issues/111)

For what it's worth, I have previously improved the error messages for this situation (see [the previous issue #63](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/issues/63) and now you should have an error that says:

```
MalformedURLException mx = new MalformedURLException(
    "SAXBuilder.build(String) expects the String to be " +
    "a systemID, but in this instance it appears to be " +
    "actual XML data.");
```

Bottom line is that you should be using:

```
Document parseddoc = new SaxBuilder().build(new StringReader(myxmlstring));
```

rolfl

Comment: Actually, it seems that code pasted by me also working fine. there was problem in somewhere else in my code. But thanks for looking into this.